# how to run a windows application developed using Visual Studio 2010 in MAC?

Tags: macos

A windows applicatio is developed in Visual Studio 2010 and teh database used was MS Access. Can i run it directly in MAC. i.e. using the EXE or do i have to do some setting or is it not possible at all.

Comment: You should ask first, "Can I run windows application on Mac?" Directly no, but there is Parallels (virtual machine for Mac), where you can run it in Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run windows application directly in MAC OS at all! But there is such a enviropment like - `mono`, which allows to compile the `C#` and .NET platform solutions for other OS. Feel free to use google with query - `Mono develop`.

From my experience - Mono isn't stable and didn't work as fine as Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not.

EXE is a windows executable file format and thus don't work on OS X, linux or any other Unix based OS. As mentioned you can use parallels wich cost money. There is a free alternative called VirtualBox. This does not provide the same features, but you have to decide for yourself.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

http://www.parallels.com/eu/

Here is a guide to how you set up VirtualBox on your MAC -> http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/virtualbox-running-windows-on-a-mac-for-free-sort-of/